# Bookmarklet to invoke onChange from actionlist in Safari on iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, onchange, bookmarklet, actionlist

My work uses a proprietary system to store medical records.  The site is coded in javascript, and we are unable to change the coding of the site.  We would like to use iPads to access the site, the site is accessed through a browser which is serving HTML.

There is a drop-down list that has an onChange value, which when an item is selected from the drop-down list onChange="doAction(this)" is invoked.  This works fine in a desktop browser, however the iPad doesn't support the onChange.  I know that an alternative is to use onBlue, however we do not have access to change the HTML.

What I was hoping we could do was to add a bookmarklet that once clicked, in principle does what the onChange event did.

The current actionlist HTML is:

```
<select class="actionList" onChange="doAction(this)" style="width:100%"><option class="actionHeading" selected value="nothing">Select action ..</option><option class="action" value="moreInfo">&nbsp;&nbsp;More Info (shortcut key ' i ')</option><option class="actionHeading" disabled>Add Electronic Form ..</option><option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-amendment-discharge">&nbsp;&nbsp;Amendment Discharge Summary</option><option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-clinical-review">&nbsp;&nbsp;Clinical Review</option><option class="action" value="xform-dischargesummary">&nbsp;&nbsp;Discharge Summary</option><option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-family-work">&nbsp;&nbsp;Family Work</option><option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-medical-review">&nbsp;&nbsp;Medical Review</option><option class="action" value="xform-medicationsummary">&nbsp;&nbsp;Medication Summary Form</option><option class="action" value="xform-operationrecord">&nbsp;&nbsp;Operation Sheet</option><option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-inpatient">&nbsp;&nbsp;Progress Notes</option><option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-weekly-summary">&nbsp;&nbsp;Weekly Summary</option></select></td>
```

The only option I would like to have in the bookmarklet is to 'select' the medical review option, i.e

```
<option class="action" value="xform-progressnotes-medical-review">&nbsp;&nbsp;Medical Review</option>
```

the javascript for onChange="doAction(this)" is:

```
function doAction(selectObj)
                {
                    var xformPrefix = 'xform-';
                    var chartPrefix = 'chart-';

                    var action = selectObj.value;
                    selectObj.selectedIndex = 0;
                    if (action == 'moreInfo')
                    {
                        moreInfo();
                    }
                    else if (action == 'referForAttn')
                    {
                        referForAttn();
                    }
                    else if(action.startsWith(chartPrefix)) {

                        var chartName = action.substring(chartPrefix.length);
                        var url;
                        var processedURL;

                        var checkExistUrl = '/udr/json/?action=chartsdescription';
                        checkExistUrl += '&patientId=630402';
                        checkExistUrl += '&chartName=' + chartName;
                        $.ajax({
                            async:false,
                            dataType:"json",
                            url:checkExistUrl,
                            success:function(data){

                                if(data.description != "")
                                {
                                    var answer = confirm(data.description);
                                }

                                if(answer || data.description == "")
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if (action.startsWith(xformPrefix))
                    {
                        var xformName = action.substring(xformPrefix.length);
                        var url;
                        var windowWidth;
                        var windowHeight;
                        var processedURL;


                            if (xformName == 'progressnotes-amendment-discharge')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=progressnotes-amendment-discharge&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dprogressnotes-amendment-discharge%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 500;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'progressnotes-clinical-review')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=progressnotes-clinical-review&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dprogressnotes-clinical-review%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 500;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'dischargesummary')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=dischargesummary&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Ddischargesummary%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 550;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'progressnotes-family-work')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=progressnotes-family-work&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dprogressnotes-family-work%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 500;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'progressnotes-medical-review')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=progressnotes-medical-review&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dprogressnotes-medical-review%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 500;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'medicationsummary')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=medicationsummary&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dmedicationsummary%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 760;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'operationrecord')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=operationrecord&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Doperationrecord%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 760;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'progressnotes-inpatient')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=progressnotes-inpatient&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dprogressnotes-inpatient%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 500;
                    }

                            if (xformName == 'progressnotes-weekly-summary')
                            {
                                url = '/oip-forms-viewer/forms/templates?udrSessionId=BF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC&formName=progressnotes-weekly-summary&patientId=630402&episodeId=458698&transactionId=&xformAction=new&sectionId=Admission';

                                processedURL = '%2Foip-forms-viewer%2Fforms%2Ftemplates%3FudrSessionId%3DBF0C3C8399163439782C67D2757477DC%26formName%3Dprogressnotes-weekly-summary%26patientId%3D630402%26episodeId%3D458698%26transactionId%3D%26xformAction%3Dnew%26sectionId%3DAdmission'

                        windowWidth = 800;
                        windowHeight = 500;
                    }




                var newForm;
                var confirmMsg = "There is another e-form opened. \n";
                confirmMsg += "Press \"Cancel\" to finish editing the open e-form\n";
                confirmMsg += "Press \"OK\" to discard it and open a new one.";
                try {
                    var location = findFrame(top, 'main').win.document.location;
                    newForm = confirm(confirmMsg);
                }
                catch(e) {
                    newForm = true;
                }
                if(newForm) {
                    try {
                        findFrame(top, 'main').win.close();
                    }
                    catch(e) {}

                    findFrame(top, 'main').win = openCentredWindow(url, 'xformWindow', windowWidth, windowHeight);

                    try {
                        // setting the window title change on window load
                        $(findFrame(top, 'main').win).load(changeEformWindowTitle);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        // nothing to report
                    }
                    try {
                        // trying to change the window title early if the on load hasn't worked
                        setTimeout('changeEformWindowTitle()', 2000);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        // nothing to report
                    }
                    try {
                        // doing it a second time in case the first attempt was too early.
                        setTimeout('changeEformWindowTitle()', 8000);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        // nothing to report
                    }
                    try {
                        // doing it a third time 40 seconds later in case it there was a pre-fill.
                        setTimeout('changeEformWindowTitle()', 40000);
                    }
                    catch(e) {
                        // nothing to report
                    }
                }
                else {
                    findFrame(top, 'main').win.focus();
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help you could provide would be very much appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to place a proxy server between the ipad and the actual product.
This proxy can then modify the html generated by the proprietary system.

You can look into nginx as a newbie friendly solution for proxying.

Cheers,
T.

PS : I dont believe bookmarklets work on iPads. Even if they did, it would be a terrible UI.